# Google sheet data validation problems

Tags: google-sheets

i'm makeing a google sheet and i'm having problems with data validation. I want to make a list that cant repeat the data. I mean, if i have this

[image]

and the i select one

[image]

i should not be able to select it another time

[image]

Any one know how to do it?

i'm trying to force ir with this custom formula

=sort(unique(PARCMÒBIL!A2:A10),1,TRUE)

This is my page list

[image]

This is a quadrant so i migth have the BUL(is a vehicle) in CAL, SOLL, INC ... and if i have the BUL 301 is CAL-Operatiu i should not be able to use it in eny more CAL cells and SOLL, INC ...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a rough copy of your sheet and think I have a solution. The data validation is created in another sheet and uses a formula to remove duplicates for each column in the front end sheet.

See the solution sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u7mp59iBrM0pFeQNPpvR2bT9iJO4VMU-YKoU2lPmAlQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Front end sheet
[image: Sheet1]

Data validation sheet
[image: Data validation sheet]

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Lucke Whelan This is working but i dont have that Master List. I will edit my post with my other page.

Comment: Maybe i should make that Master List